# Mail Sending Limit with Gmail API via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, quota

The Mail Sending Quota for Google Apps Script is 1500 as stated in the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). However, As mentioned in the [Gmail API Document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota), mail sending quota will be same as applied to Mail Sending Limit (2000).   Does the AppScript quota limit also applies if Gmail API is used?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the GmailApp service of Google Apps Script, the GSuite mail quota is 1500 recipients per day. However, if you are using the Gmail API (and not the GmailApp service), the higher quota of Gmail would be available.

Answer (score 0):

[Gmail API Quota](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota) says Daily Usage Limit is "1,000,000,000 quota units per day for your application."

And the Quota Units for messages.send is 100, so it seems you can send at most 10,000,000. **However, we need to use other API Methods, so the amount would be less than 10,000,000.**